# Distribution of an Euclidean norm

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics

If $X = \begin{pmatrix} X_{1} \\ X_{2} \end{pmatrix}$ (with $X_{1},X_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$) follows a gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$. What is the distribution of $\Vert X_{1} \Vert^{2}$ (where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$).

If $\Pi=\left( \begin{array}{c|c}
I_{n} &\ 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$, I know that $X'=\Pi X = \begin{pmatrix} X_{1} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}(\Pi \mu, \Pi \Sigma {}^t \Pi)$ and $\Vert X_{1} \Vert^{2} = \Vert \Pi X \Vert^{2}$. I had the following idea : if $\mu' = \Pi \mu$ and $\Sigma' = \Pi \Sigma {}^t \Pi$, let $\Gamma {}^t \Gamma = \Sigma'$ be the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma'$. Then, $\Gamma^{-1} X' \sim \mathcal{N}(\Gamma^{-1}\mu',I_{n})$. So, I know that $\Vert \Gamma^{-1} X'\Vert^{2}$ follows a $\chi^{2}(n,\Vert \Gamma^{-1} \mu' \Vert^{2})$ but I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag, & note that we treat such questions differently (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help))--although, of course, they are still welcome.

Comment: This is not a homework question but it could be one. I've looked up different courses on random vectors but I didn't find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are essentially asking for the sum of squares of dependent gaussian random variables. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables) seems to be an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. $\Vert X_{1} \Vert^{2} = {}^t X_{1} X_{1}$ is actually a quadratic form in the random vector $X_{1}$. I'll look into that !